# Copy Maven Dependency Jars while Run On Server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss7.x

I have create a Dynamic Web Project with Maven Dependency Enabled. Now when I am running the application in my JBoss AS7 server in built in Eclipse the jar's from the Maven Dependency does not copied in the lib of the WAR file and for that reason I am getting ClassNotFoundException.

How can I solve this problem?

---

Edit:

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>EMSApplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>EMSApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>googlecode</id>
            <url>http://jqwicket.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.jqwicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>jqwicket</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
             <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
             <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>cglib</groupId>
             <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
             <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you using M2E and M2E for WTP?

Comment: How did you define the dependencies as scope provided ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have defined the dependencies in the pom.xml. This added the jars in Maven Dependencies of the Library. Now, since I don't know how to automatically add those jars in the classpath, so I am manually copying those jars and put them into the lib folder of WEB-INF and then set those jars in classpath from project properties.

Comment: How have you defined your dependencies? Can you post an example? Have you defined the packaging of your project to war ? Can you post an excerpt of your poms?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have updated my question. No I didn't add any packaging strategy in the pom.xml.

Comment: Of course you did: <packaging>war</packaging>...thats ok and correct. How does your folder structure look like ? src/main/java, src/main/webapp ?

Comment: Have you tested if your war file will be produced by mvn clean package and tried to deploy it manually into JBoss 7 if it works correctly? Furthermore which version of Eclipse are you using ? Have you installed m2e Plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise by packaging strategy I wanted to mean that I didn't defined any build property in the pom. Yes I have m2e installed in indigo. Also the project structure is not contain src/main/java or src/main/webapp, since as I told before I created a Dynamic Web Project then I converted into Maven project from Configure option of Project right click menu. Also I am not packaging using mvn, what I am doing is simple Export->War. The path has been set pointing the JBoss. Since I had set the classpath as described before, the war does contain all the jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use Maven you have to follow the conventions of Maven which is the [folder structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and you shouldn't try to go around cause you will loose that combat.
My suggestion is to first get your Maven build working and then import it into your IDE and continue working there after the build on command works fine.